# Remove backslashes from url fields in .bib entry

Tags: biblatex, urls

The problem I'm having is that urls with backslashes in the `.bib` file are not linking correctly.

I'm using Mendeley to generate a .bib file that gets imported and used in the references section of a document via the `biblatex` package.

Mendeley escapes some special characters in the url field with a backslash (so _ turns to \_). As I understand it, `biblatex` wants those urls without escaped characters, as is. This is most likely what's causing the problem.

So I'm figuring there isn't a clean package option that tells `biblatex` to do something proper with the backslashes in url fields. If there is, that would be an ideal solution to the problem.

If there's not, I was thinking of doing a for loop over the `url` fields within LaTeX and stripping any '\'. But I'm not yet familiar enough with LaTeX programming to do this.

Comment: The answer below is correct, but really Mendeley is in the wrong here: in the `url` field, no escaping should be done, `biblatex` or not.

Comment: @JosephWright: Maybe so, but the *doi* field will need to be escaped for BibTeX, whereas by default, BibLatex wants to have it unescaped (as otherwise, the escaping `\` will be printed as a part of the DOI).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `biber` is used as a backend the solution is to use `\DeclareSourcemap` to clean the `url`.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url,
        match=\regexp{\\_},
        replace=\regexp{_}]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I just changed {\\_}->{\}, {_}->{}, so that all backslashes are stripped.

Answer (score 0):

To do it via a command line (for inclusion in other processing tool) you can do a short python script:

```
f=open("in.bib", "r")
for line in f:
    if "url" in line:
        print line.replace("\\_","_"),
    else:
        print line,
```

and launch it like this:

```
python filter.py > out.bib
```